# NetworkStream.Read IO.Exception on deployed application

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am developing C# clent/server application based on two windows services, which are set up on a clients(.NET 2) machine and windows server 2003.

Sometimes I get an exception

> Unable to read data from the transport connection. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

It doesn't happen at a constant period in time. From service restart on the server, it takes sometimes 2 weeks or even just 1 day until the exception begins to occur.

How do I correct this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Hardly any information to even understand the issue, please post some code and exception details

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code where the exception occurs, and to know which end of the connection it occurs at. That exception usually means the other end of the connection has closed. This could happen for many reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like intermittent network problems. It's quite common in wireless networks, and it can also happen on wired networks from time to time (Ethernet is not a deterministic protocol). The reasons can be various. However, in addition to fixing your network problems, I would strongly recommend to make your service resilient against network problems.

(Think about the simple case that someone unplugs the server's network cable for a short moment: If your application crashes with an unhandled exception, administrator intervention is required to get it running again. You don't want that. That's not good behaviour for a service.)

Thus, your service should catch IO exceptions, make an entry into the Windows application log and retry the operation *a little bit later* (to avoid flooding the event log or putting unnecessary load on the machine or the network).

Comment: That exactly what I do: catch the exceptions, write it to windows log and retry later, but i want to understand the reason because once the exception happend it continiue to happen until i make restart of service on server

Comment: @alexyz: I see! In that case, it you might need to re-establish the connection once it has been lost. What type of connection do you use? It might be helpful to show a bit of (simplified) code in your question.

Comment: I cannot paste some code because the development machine not connected to the internet(and connot be connected)

Comment: @alexyz: Then you will probably need to re-establish the TCP connection instead of just retrying the Send operation.